# Servlet and maven

Tags: java, maven, servlet

Использование Maven с технологией Servlet. Подробная информация об этом.

Comment: вы определитесь с вопросом: нужен или обязателен?

Comment: А что между ними общего?

Comment: @Caulfield мавен это всего лиш тул, который помогает вам собирать проект (компилировать, загружать зависимости, подкладывать их в класспаф, собирать жар, запускать тесты т .д). Сервлет это программа, которая выполняется на веб сервере(чаще всего). Вы можете компилировать свои сервлеты и собирать в жары/вары и другим тулом. Например градлом, или антом. Или даже командой javac.

Comment: @Caulfield мавен нужен, для того, чтобы собирать сервлеты было проще. А чем собирать - выбирайте сами.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется это вопрос из разряда: нужна ли мне IDE для написания кода... Можно ведь писать и в простом текстовом редакторе, совсем без IDE. С другой стороны с IDE, все же удобнее.... Тоже самое и с maven'ом или его аналогом gradle.

Можно и в ручную весь проект собирать, но Maven позволяет это делать удобнее, быстрее. Укажешь какую-то зависимость (библиотеку) в pom файле, и она тебе сама закачается, перед билдом автоматом прогонятся тесты, проект соберется в нужном тебе виде (jar, war...) и в нужную тебе директорию с нужным именем... и многое другое (можно например обфускацию кода прикрутить или еще что-нибудь). И все это нажатием одной кнопочки. Удобно.

В отношении сервлетов. Вот у тебя проект, ты хочешь проверять в процессе разработки, как он работает... при этом тебе важно чтобы все происходило автоматически. Ты на кнопку нажал, а там все запустилось и тебе показало прямо в браузере... Для этого тебе нужно проект собрать в фаил *.war (вот Maven этот war тебе и соберет как раз)... потом IDE его подхватит и задеплоит в Tomcat, который сама для тебя запустит.

Вообще, есть хорошее видео у Немчинского, в котором роль и возможности Maven подробно объясняются
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAbZVA4tK6M

Answer (score 0):

Ну как бэ: для собственно написания сервлетов *maven* вроде как не обязателен.

Для написания сервлетов точно нужна библиотека, а вот как прикрутить библиотеку к исходникам - тут начинается и самое интересное. Вариантов тьма:

1. Вручную выкачать и прикрутить его в `CLASSPATH` или к IDE
2. Использовать *maven*, который сам выкачает его из сети
3. Использовать *gradle*, который также сам выкачает из сети (как правило из серверов maven)
4. Ну и т.д.

Дальше начинается другая история деплоймента (разворачивания) сервлета в контейнере. Тоже вариантов много:

1. Врукопашную через copy, с перезапуском сервера
2. Воспользоваться средствами самого сервера/контейнера
3. Использовать *maven*
4. Применить *gradle*
5. Что-то из набора devops: *docker* и проч.

Как то так.